# Crashes when i try to access internet

Tags: android, debugging

evertime i use this code it says theres a nullpointer exception

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
  if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
    {
      gotoWeb interwebs=new gotoWeb();
      interwebs.go();
    }
return true;
}

public class gotoWeb extends Activity
{
  public void go() 
  {
    Intent ins = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);  
    ins.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
    startActivity(ins);
  }
}
```

I cant seem to figure out what i havent assigned im almost done with my project and this seems to be holding me back

Comment: 1. please attach error message | 2. have you set INTERNET permission?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't just extend `Activity`, construct it and then use it. Read up on the [activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) to see how to properly create one. The reason you're getting an NPE is that your Activity -- which derives from Context -- is calling startActivity() which is a Context method within a Context that hasn't been initialized since you haven't used the appropriate mechanism for creating your Activity.

That said, I'm not sure why you're trying to construct an Activity just to start another activity that launches the web browser. Why not create the Intent and start it from within your onTouchEvent()? I assume that touch handler exists within an Activity or something with a Context available.

Comment: Those last two words made the bulb in my head go off thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is really a bit confusing.  Why do you have a class that extends Activity but that doesn't override any the built-in methods like onCreate() and onCreateView()?  An Activity is a container for a UI and all the behaviour that should go along with that single screen.  This includes navigation, buttons that require click handlers, etc.  Yet, your class doesn't override the most basic methods that return an inflated UI hierarchy.

Since you never actually start an instance of GoToWeb using startActivity, none of the callbacks ever get called, which means nothing would ever be drawn to the screen.